# Return records in chronological order, given a separation factor

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, geospatial, spatial-query

I have a massive table in **SQLServer 2008**, it contains the position reported by technicians every minute. I need to report on this table but in order to control the amount of records that are displayed in the report both a time and distance separation factors need to be taken into account.

So, a query may look like

```
"Return all records with no less than 5 minutes and/or 300 feet between them".
```

The time part is done, but I'm having a hard time with the distance factor. I have the latitude and longitude for each point, and I have no problem if I need to include a **SQLServer 2008 spatial UDT** in order to resolve the problem.

Things I have considered:

1. Bring the records by the time factor, and apply the separation constrain in the client by calculating the distance between adjacent points and discard those which falls inside the the factor. (the easiest, but it must be the one consuming more resources).
2. Keep the last record per technician in a cache, pre-calculate the distance between the record and its predecessor, and resolve the constrain in the client. (should consume less resources than 1) since the distance is pre-calculated, however *and since the table is BIG* It will increase the size of the dataset, not sure if the space is worth the processing savings).
3. Use the spatial functions in **SQLServer 2008**, but honestly I had been reading and I couldn't find anything that helps me resolve this type of requirement. Any GIS expert??

I would like to go with the best option possible (maybe not listed above?) and IMO should be the one using the SQLserver features most efficiently.

Comment: Possibly better asked in http://dba.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Thanks, posted here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9102/sqlserver-2008-return-records-in-chronological-order-given-a-separation-facto as per your advice. Since this question involves other skills (GIS) I'm leaving it here too...

Answer (score 1):

What Raciel is asking, is how to "simplify" a list of points by a distance's factor. Suppose you have a list of one hundred spatial points sorted by dateTime, and the distance between one point from the previous is exactly 150 feets, he need to get just the list of points which distance is 300 feet, the result set should be a list of around 50 points... 
I just imagine do this using a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is:

```
3949.99 * arcos(sin(LAT1) * sin(LAT2) + cos(LAT1) * cos(LAT2) * cos(LONG1 - LONG2))
```

The radius of Earth is 3949.99 miles. All rest is self explanatory. This formula is Great Circle distance calculation formula.

Comment: Muhammand, thanks for your answer but the problem I have is actually not how to calculate the distance between 2 points; but given a sequence of points in chronological order, how to return only those no less than X feet.

For instance, lets say that a technician reported his position every  minute, and he is walking... I'm interesting only in see points only every 300 feet or 600 feet. This allow to run coarse or fine grain reports.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to SQL 2008, the most common solution was to use a UDF to calculate the great-circle distance between two points on a sphere. [The Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is probably the most commonly used method.

Of course the Earth is not actually a perfect sphere, but this was considered "good enough" for most uses.

In SQL 2008, as you anticipated, such calculations are simplified and made more accurate by the introduction of the Geography and Geometry data types. Here's a brief sample of how you can use them to simplify distance calculations.

```
DECLARE @locations TABLE(locname VARCHAR(100), coord geography)
DECLARE @loc1 geography
DECLARE @loc2 geography


INSERT INTO @locations 
VALUES('HOME', geography::Point(-81.810194, 41.478156, 4326))   --Note: Lat, Long, SRID
                                                                --The 4326 is the SRID (spatial reference id) used by SQL as 
                                                                --a reference to the WGS 84 Standard. This is the same reference
                                                                --used by the GPS system
INSERT INTO @locations 
VALUES('WORK', geography::Point(-81.687771, 41.498227, 4326))

SELECT * FROM @locations

SELECT @loc1 = coord FROM @locations WHERE locname = 'HOME'
SELECT @loc2 = coord FROM @locations WHERE locname = 'WORK'

SELECT @loc1.STDistance(@loc2) * 3.2808399  --STDistance is in meters so we multiply to convert to feet
```

The SRID is the key to the improved accuracy. The [WGS 84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) specification to which it refers includes a standardized coordinate system and a reference ellipsoid.  In other words, it accounts for the non-spherical nature of the Earth, giving better results than a pure spherical Great Circle calculation.

If GIS accuracy is important to your work, this is the simplest way to implement it in SQL 2008.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for your answer. The problem here is not how to calculate the distance between 2 arbitrary points, but how to extract a set of points from a dataset given a distance factor. Please check the explanation I gave to Muhammad bellow.